# Add object to Context EntityFramework 4 without SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, datacontext

Is there a way to add object to de dataContext without committing the changes, when I use

```
ctx.Articles.AddObject(newart);
```

the `newart` **doesn't appear** inth e context `ctx`, the only way i was able to do that is by saveing changes `ctx.SaveChanges` , unfortunatly that save changes to the DB, & i don't want to, is there a way to do that, Any help will be *appreciated*

Answer (score 4):

**May work in EF4**

You should be able to get all currently tracked objects via the `ObjectStateManager` of your `ObjectContext` like

```
var articles = ctx.ObjectStateManager
                    // Get all entries for added/changed/modified entities
                    .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added |
                                           EntityState.Unchanged |
                                           EntityState.Modified)
                    // select the entity objects from the entries
                    .Select(entry=>entry.Entity)
                    // we're only interested in Article objects
                    .OfType<Article>();
```

*Note*: Since I haven't installed EF4 so I couldn't verify this solution. But I remember darkly having done this successfully some time ago :). It might not be very performant when done with very large object sets though ...

**Works for EF 5**

You can use the[`Local`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.local%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) Property of the `DbSet` class. This property represents the object currently tracked by the Context (i.e. all objects that are currently loaded and/or locally added without those being deleted). Accessing the `Local` property never does a DB query.

So you can use `ctx.Articles.Local` and get a data set which contains your `newart` object (along with any objects loaded by previous queries)

Comment: is that valid @MartinStettner on EF4

Comment: I believe it is, but I didn't find any information about this quickly (and I currently only have EF5 installed). But you should be able to easily verify if the `Local` property exists in EF4: if it does, I'm pretty sure it works the same way as in EF5 ...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried to figure out a solution for EF4, I'm curious if this works :) ...